# Regex lookaround start of line

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex https://regex101.com/r/wRBBAz/1

```
(?<=\s|^|\.)[^ \.]+(?=\s*(\())
```

Testing with input

```
test1 {...}
test2();
```

I specified start of line (^) in lookaround so I don't understand why it selects

```
}
test2
```

instead of only

```
test2
```

Comment: You are missing `}` in `[^ \.]`, it should be `[^ {\.]` -> `(?<=\s|^|\.)[^} |\.]+(?=\s*(\())`

Comment: It is not really matching `}`, remove 2nd line and you will see that. Due to use of negated character class `[^ \.]` it matches `}` when there are more lines. That is where `[^\s.]` will helps as it won't match across the lines

Comment: So you may use: [`(?<=[\s.]|^)[^\s.]+(?=\h*\()`](https://regex101.com/r/wRBBAz/2)

Comment: What about this `[\w\d]+(?=\(.*\))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `[^ .]` matches any char but a space and a dot, that is, it matches line break chars.

You can use

```
(?<![^.\s])[^\s.]+(?=\s*(\())
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ofDJoN/2)

*Details*

- `(?<![^.\s])` - a negative lookbehind that matches a location that is either at the start of string or immediately preceded with a dot or whitespace
- `[^\s.]+` - **any one or more chars other than whitespace and `.`**
- `(?=\s*(\())` - a positive lookahead making sure there is zero or more whitespces and then a `(` (captured into Group 1) immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Any ideas on how to improve the answer are welcome.